# Commuting operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, commutator, observables

If 2 Hermitian operators share a basis of eigenfunctions, then they commute.

Is the converse true? If 2 Hermitian operators commute, then they should share a basis of eigenfunctions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither statement (as you originally phrased them) is really correct.

- You can conclude that two operators commute if they share a *complete* set of common eigenfunctions.
- If two operators commute, then you are guaranteed the existence of one complete set of eigenfunctions which is common to both operators. However, you are *not* guaranteed that all the eigenfunctions of one will be eigenfunctions of the other.